# flashing pictures in div

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, refresh

i have a div on a php page that automatically load a php page every 10 sec with this code :

```
       $(document).ready(function () {

     var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {


         $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: 're.php',
             data: {
                 get_param: 'value'
             },
             success: function (data) {
                 var names = data
                 if (yn != 0) $('#content').html(data);
             }
         });


     }, 10000);


 });
```

My problem is that in the page loaded i have pictures .So every 10 seconds some of them are flashing (text is not flashing). Note that some pictures are changed in these 10 seconds . I have noticed that only these pictures are flashing when the div is updated ... what is wrong ?

Comment: what is yn in if(yn !=0)?

Comment: this is a condition to put or not  the html inside the div , it is a way to stop the update of the div ..

Comment: success: function (data) { } in data what you have

Comment: the new html data that i want to load in the div

Comment: what's ur issue whether text is not flashing or anything else?

Comment: only pictures are flashing and this is the problem . If the div has new pictures they are flashing every 10 seconds

Comment: that's y i am asking what u have in data? Could u show me the content u used in the data to load in div

Comment: i have nothing in data at first . Then in data i have the html code for the div .

Comment: Are you replacing the image by new one in the ajax call

Comment: no i don't replace it in the ajax call . I replace images from another page and then they are visible in the div . But new images ara flashing when the div is updated .

Comment: as you can see in the code i reload the div every 10 seconds . On my web site i use gzip compression . This may cause problem ?